# Problem in creating a service in a contair to inject a dependency into a class

Tags: dependency-injection, slim

I am trying to inject a dependency into a class in Slim framework. I created a service in a container to do it but I got this error.

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController::__construct() must be an instance of Api\Models\StudentWorkPrice, none given, called in /studentwork/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 93 and defined in /studentwork/src/api/Controllers/StudentWorkPriceController.php on line 29

My code is as below:

dependencies.php

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['\Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController']=function ($c){
    $studentWorkPrice = new \Api\Models\StudentWorkPrice();
    return new \Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController($c,$studentWorkPrice);

};
```

index.php

```
use Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController;
require __DIR__ . '/src/dependencies.php';

$app->get('/stuworkprice[/{params:.*}]',StudentWorkPriceController::class . ':select')->setName('StudentWorkPrice.select');
```

StudentWorkPriceController.php

```
use Api\Models\StudentWorkPrice as StudentWorkPrice;

class StudentWorkPriceController
{
   // protected $logger;
   // protected $pdo;
    protected $stuWorkPrice;

    /**
     * StudentWorkPriceController constructor.
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, StudentWorkPrice $stuWorkPrice)
    {
       // $this->logger = $container->get('logger');
       // $this->pdo = $container->get('pdo');
        $this->stuWorkPrice = $stuWorkPrice;
    }

    public function select(){
    }
}
```

It seems that the service I defined in container doesn't run! Could anybody please help me to figure out what's happening here!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Problem solved! just replaced `$container['\Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController'] ` with `$container[Api\Controllers\StudentWorkPriceController::class] ` in dependencies.php

Comment: Yes. As you spotted, the `key` names are different. Easiest to use `::class` in cases.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your comment. Whenever I have a a question about Slim and I search it here I find some really helpful comments from you. Thanks a lot!